# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Tags: java

I have written this code in JAVA and every time I try to execute it, there is a runtime error that occurs and it's like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>     at Solution.main(Solution.java:26)

My actual code is like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int scores[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            scores[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        int alice[]=new int[m];
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            alice[j]=scan.nextInt();
        }

         int ranks1[]=new int [n];
        ranks1[0]=1;
        for(int k=1;k<(n+1);k++){
                 if((scores[k])<(scores[k-1])){
                        ranks1[k]=ranks1[k-1]+1;
                 }    
                 else if((scores[k])==(scores[k-1]))
                 ranks1[k]=ranks1[k-1];

        }
        int rank2[] = new int[m];
        for(int a=0,s=(n-1);(a<m) && (s>=0); ){
            if(alice[a]<scores[s]){
                rank2[a]=ranks1[s]+1;
                a++;
            }
            if(alice[a]==scores[s]){
                rank2[a]=ranks1[s];
                a++; 
                s--;
            }
            if(alice[a]>scores[s]){
                s--;
            }
        }

        for(int l=0;l<m;l++){
            System.out.println(rank2[l]);
        }

    }
}
```

I have googled this issue many times and it tells me that this occurs if I try to access any illegal index in arrays. But I am not trying to do so. Can anybody help me? If I'm wrong somewhere, please correct me.

Comment: You are wrong on line 26. Which line is line 26?

Comment: what should the program do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are trying to access an illegal index. The first time you do so is here:

```
for(int k=1;k<(n+1);k++){
  if((scores[k])<(scores[k-1])){
  //
```

What happens when you try to access `scores[k]`, and k = n? Remember that array indexes start at 0. This means that the maximum index of an array with size `n` will be `n-1`, not `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at 0. This means that in every `for` loop where you start the iterator from `1` and access the array in index `k` (with k being the size of the array) you are actually trying to access the index that follows the end of the array, giving you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an index in an array that is out of array length

and that happens in this code snippet

```
 int ranks1[] = new int[n];
            ranks1[0] = 1;
            for (int k = 1 ; k < (n + 1) ; k++) {
                if ((scores[k]) < (scores[k - 1])) {
                    ranks1[k] = ranks1[k - 1] + 1;
                } else if ((scores[k]) == (scores[k - 1]))
                    ranks1[k] = ranks1[k - 1];

            }
```

the best way to solve this is to debug it

that's good practice for you now. please chek this [Debugging](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php)